# little o notation in equations

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Consider the real-valued functions $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Suppose I have an equation saying
$$ f(x)=g(x)+o(1) \tag{$*$}$$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$, where $o(1)$ denotes a class of functions $h(\cdot)$ characterised by $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} h(x)=0$.

Is it possible to move the little o symbol across the equality operator? In other words, can I rewrite $(*)$ as

$$
f(x)-o(1)=g(x) \text{?}
$$

Comment: Yes, or, equivalently, $f(x)+o(1)=g(x)$, or $f(x)-g(x)=o(1)$, or $f(x)+o(1)=g(x)+o(1)$ (ok, this last one is rather awkward, but still correct), or...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People will know what you mean if you write that. That said, the one notation which is not prone to misuse is

$$f(x)-g(x) \in o(1).$$

People don't actually write this nearly as often as the equality notation, though.

Comment: Thanks @Ian, could you clarify a bit more this point: I'm wondering whether writing $f(x)=g(x)+o(1)$ is the same as writing $f(x)=g(x)-o(1)$ or $f(x)+o(1)=g(x)$ since for each $h()$ s.t. $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}h(x)=0$ also $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}-h(x)=0$.

Comment: @STF Did you read my comment on main?

Comment: yes, thanks a lot